# How can I prevent the closure of my Bootstrap modal dialog when I resize past its maximum size?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, interact.js

I'm using interact.js to allow users to resize a modal dialog that I produce using Bootstrap 3.3.7. There's a problem that when the user initiates the resize and moves the mouse pointer so that the dialog is resized past its maximum size, the modal is closed as soon as the user releases the mouse button. This does not happen if the user is shrinking the modal. The following code snippet shows the issue.

```js
var makeModalButton = document.getElementById("makeModal");
var modalTemplate =
  '\
<div class="modal" style="position: absolute" tabindex="1">\
  <div class="modal-dialog">\
    <div class="modal-content">\
      <div class="modal-header">\
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" \
         aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>\
        <h3 class="modal-title">Foo</h3>\
      </div>\
      <div class="modal-body">\
        <p>Foo foo.</p>\
      </div>\
      <div class="modal-footer">\
      </div>\
    </div>\
  </div>\
</div>';

function updateRect(el, dx, dy) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var width = rect.width + dx;
  var height = rect.height + dy;
  el.style.width = width + 'px';
  el.style.height = height + 'px';
}

$(makeModalButton).on("click", function() {
  var $modal = $(modalTemplate);
  document.body.appendChild($modal[0]);
  var body = $modal[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
  var content = $modal[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
  $modal.modal();
  interact(content)
    .resizable({})
    .on('resizemove', function(event) {
      var target = event.target;

      updateRect(target, event.dx, event.dy);
      updateRect(body, event.dx, event.dy);
    });
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.modal-dialog {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Click the button "Make a modal". Click on the bottom footer of the modal to resize it, and move the pointer down until the modal stop resizing. Release the mouse button. The modal will close.
</p>
<button id="makeModal">Make a modal</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the mouse pointer moves outside the content of the modal, **the mouse release is registered on a backdrop that Bootstrap creates to catch clicks outside the modal**. Such clicks close the modal.

The following is a proof of concept. The key is the addition of these two event listeners:

```
    .on('resizestart', function() {
      var modal = $modal.data('bs.modal');
      modal.ignoreBackdropClick = true;
    })
    .on('resizeend', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var modal = $modal.data('bs.modal');
        modal.ignoreBackdropClick = false;
      }, 0);
    })
```

We use `var modal = $modal.data('bs.modal')` to get the JavaScript object that Bootstrap creates to store the modal's state. In the `resizestart` handler we set the `.ignoreBackdropClick` property, which tells Bootstrap to ignore the next click on the backdrop. In the `resizeend` handler we want to reset that property. However due to the way events are happening, we cannot reset it right away. Instead we schedule the reset for the next iteration of the event loop, which allows Bootstrap to perform its housekeeping first. (If we clear the property too soon it is as if we never set it in the first place.)

The principle works but I'm not particularly happy with relying on a part of Bootstrap that is not documented. I'll sure be curious about alternative solutions that don't require relying on undocumented parts of Bootstrap.

A code snippet illustrating this solution follows. The "Make a faulty modal" replicates the issue in the question. The "Make a good modal" button shows the fix.

```js
var makeFaultyModalButton = document.getElementById("makeFaultyModal");
var makeGoodModalButton = document.getElementById("makeGoodModal");
var modalTemplate = '\
<div class="modal" style="position: absolute" tabindex="1">\
  <div class="modal-dialog">\
    <div class="modal-content">\
      <div class="modal-header">\
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" \
         aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>\
        <h3 class="modal-title">Foo</h3>\
      </div>\
      <div class="modal-body"><p>Foo foo.</p></div>\
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>\
    </div>\
  </div>\
</div>';

function updateRect(el, dx, dy) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var width = rect.width + dx;
  var height = rect.height + dy;
  el.style.width = width + 'px';
  el.style.height = height + 'px';
}

$(makeFaultyModalButton).on("click", function() {
  var $modal = $(modalTemplate);
  document.body.appendChild($modal[0]);
  var body = $modal[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
  var content = $modal[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
  $modal.modal();
  interact(content)
    .resizable({})
    .on('resizemove', function(event) {
      var target = event.target;

      updateRect(target, event.dx, event.dy);
      updateRect(body, event.dx, event.dy);
    });
});

$(makeGoodModalButton).on("click", function() {
  var $modal = $(modalTemplate);
  document.body.appendChild($modal[0]);
  var body = $modal[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
  var content = $modal[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
  $modal.modal();
  interact(content)
    .resizable({})
    .on('resizestart', function() {
      var modal = $modal.data('bs.modal');
      modal.ignoreBackdropClick = true;
    })
    .on('resizeend', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var modal = $modal.data('bs.modal');
        modal.ignoreBackdropClick = false;
      }, 0);
    })
    .on('resizemove', function(event) {
      var target = event.target;

      updateRect(target, event.dx, event.dy);
      updateRect(body, event.dx, event.dy);
    });
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.modal-dialog {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>
<button id="makeFaultyModal">Make a faulty modal</button>
<button id="makeGoodModal">Make a good modal</button>
```